# Convert Curl to Unirest

Tags: php, curl, unirest

This is a curl request from Stripe API curl method:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
   -u sk_test_**********: \
   -d managed=false \
   -d country=US \
   -d email="bob@example.com"
```

Right now I have this unirest code:

```
<?php Unirest\Request::auth(Config::get("stripe.secret.api_key"), '');

        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type" => "application/json"
        );
        $body    = array(  
           "managed" => $_managed,
           "country" => $_country,
           "email"   => $_email,
        );
        $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts", $headers, $body);
        return array(
            'status'  => 'success',
            'message' => $response
        ); ?>
```

Stripe returns method is wrong. I think its the `-u` param in curl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about `Unirest`. As you are facing issue with `-u` header, you can use the authorization parameter inside the url as below.

```
https://sk_test_RxRTXF1CDHuRw3ZUdynxnG6P:@api.stripe.com/v1/accounts
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Remove header `"Content-Type" => "application/json"` from your code. You are not passing json there.

Comment: But what parameter is -u sk_test_ASX21312FCA?

Comment: tried this `https://sk_test_RxRTXF1CDHuRw3ZUdynxnG6P:@api.stripe.com/v1/accounts` didnt work

Comment: It can happen that your Unirest (or curl) is not configured for ssl. I didn't see any document regarding ssl on Unirest., except this: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php#ssl-validation and it is not a good idea to disable validation.